# NULL not allowed in foreign key in @PostPersist method with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, quarkus

I'm using Quarkus with Hibernate and Resteasy.

When an entity is persited, I want to automatically create a second entity that references the first.

I tried using a `@PostPersist` annotated method, but it fails with an SQL exception. When the method is called manually it works.

MWE:

```
CREATE TABLE "entity_a" (
    "id" IDENTITY
);

CREATE TABLE "entity_b" (
    "id" IDENTITY,
    "entity_a_id" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ("entity_a_id") REFERENCES "entity_a"("id"),
);

@Entity
public class EntityA {
    
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    // getter, setter

    @PostPersist
    public void postPersist() {
        EntityB b = new EntityB();
        b.setEntityA(this);
        JpaOperations.getEntityManager().persist(b);
    }
}

@Entity
public class EntityB {
    
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToOne
    private EntityA entityA;

    // getters, setters
}


// in the rest resource class
    @POST
    @Transactional
    public void create() {
        EntityA a = new EntityA();
        JpaOperations.getEntityManager().persist(a);
    }
```

When the action is called, I get the following error:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "entity_a_id"
NULL not allowed for column "entity_a_id"; SQL statement:
insert into "entity_b" ("id", "entity_a_id") values (null, ?) [23502-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.table.Column.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Column.java:374)
    at org.h2.table.Table.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Table.java:798)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:177)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:134)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:102)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:261)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:199)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:153)
    at io.agroal.pool.wrapper.PreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractSelectingDelegate.performInsert(AbstractSelectingDelegate.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3200)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3806)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:330)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:720)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:706)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.entitymanager.TransactionScopedEntityManager.persist(TransactionScopedEntityManager.java:116)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.entitymanager.ForwardingEntityManager.persist(ForwardingEntityManager.java:27)
    at example.EntityA.postPersist(EntityA.java:24)
    ...
```

When I remove the `@PostPersist` annotation and call the method from the rest resource (after `getEntityManager().persist`) it works as expected.

When I log the id value inside `postPersist`, it is set. Why does this fail and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your static access is a giant red flag with blinking lights.

Comment: I tried it with injected objects, same effect.

Comment: Maybe you can try bidirectional mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's strange but right behaviour. Basically the `entityManager` doesn't have to generate identity immediately when `persist()` called. It depends on the selected IdentifierGenerator's strategy.

However `IDENTITY` indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary keys for the entity using a database identity column, it's only guaranteed to be assigned when the transaction commits or flush() is called.

There are many solutions and workarounds to solve this problem.

**Solution #1: Change generation strategy**

As far as I know the `SEQUENCE` strategy might be fine but honestly I haven't checked. It's just a strong perception.

**Solution #2: Use merge instead of persist**

A smart solution using `merge()` to persist entities. The point is when `merge()` called on a new entity instance then a new managed entity instance is created and the state of the original entity is copied to a managed instance of the same entity. Easily an SQL SELECT statement is executed to retrieve a managed entity from the database.

So just replace

```java
JpaOperations.getEntityManager().persist(b);
// and
JpaOperations.getEntityManager().persist(a);
```

by

```java
JpaOperations.getEntityManager().merge(b);
// and
JpaOperations.getEntityManager().merge(a);
```

As you can see the following log entries Hibernate retrieves previously persisted (merged) `EntityA` from the database.

```sh
2020-12-28 23:44:09,822 TRACE [org.hib.eng.spi.IdentifierValue] (executor-thread-1) ID unsaved-value: 0
2020-12-28 23:44:09,822 TRACE [org.hib.eve.int.EntityState] (executor-thread-1) Transient instance of: io.github.zforgo.stackoverflow.quarkus.model.EntityB
2020-12-28 23:44:09,822 TRACE [org.hib.eve.int.DefaultMergeEventListener] (executor-thread-1) Merging transient instance
2020-12-28 23:44:09,822 TRACE [org.hib.eng.spi.IdentifierValue] (executor-thread-1) ID unsaved-value: 0
2020-12-28 23:44:09,822 TRACE [org.hib.eng.spi.IdentifierValue] (executor-thread-1) ID unsaved-value: 0
2020-12-28 23:44:09,822 TRACE [org.hib.eve.int.DefaultLoadEventListener] (executor-thread-1) Loading entity: [io.github.zforgo.stackoverflow.quarkus.model.EntityA#4]
2020-12-28 23:44:09,822 TRACE [org.hib.eve.int.DefaultLoadEventListener] (executor-thread-1) Attempting to resolve: [io.github.zforgo.stackoverflow.quarkus.model.EntityA#4]
2020-12-28 23:44:09,822 TRACE [org.hib.eve.int.DefaultLoadEventListener] (executor-thread-1) Object not resolved in any cache: [io.github.zforgo.stackoverflow.quarkus.model.EntityA#4]
2020-12-28 23:44:09,822 TRACE [org.hib.per.ent.AbstractEntityPersister] (executor-thread-1) Fetching entity: [io.github.zforgo.stackoverflow.quarkus.model.EntityA#4]
2020-12-28 23:44:09,822 DEBUG [org.hib.SQL] (executor-thread-1) select entitya0_.id as id1_0_0_ from EntityA entitya0_ where entitya0_.id=?
2020-12-28 23:44:09,823 TRACE [org.hib.res.jdb.int.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl] (executor-thread-1) Registering statement [wrapped[ prep7: select entitya0_.id as id1_0_0_ from EntityA entitya0_ where entitya0_.id=? ]]
2020-12-28 23:44:09,823 TRACE [org.hib.eng.jdb.int.JdbcCoordinatorImpl] (executor-thread-1) Registering last query statement [wrapped[ prep7: select entitya0_.id as id1_0_0_ from EntityA entitya0_ where entitya0_.id=? ]]
2020-12-28 23:44:09,823 TRACE [org.hib.typ.des.sql.BasicBinder] (executor-thread-1) binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [4]
2020-12-28 23:44:09,823 TRACE [org.hib.loa.pla.exe.int.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader] (executor-thread-1) Bound [2] parameters total
```

The most relevant part which is missing when use `persist()` is:

```sh
Loading entity: [io.github.zforgo.stackoverflow.quarkus.model.EntityA#4]
Attempting to resolve: [io.github.zforgo.stackoverflow.quarkus.model.EntityA#4]
Object not resolved in any cache: [io.github.zforgo.stackoverflow.quarkus.model.EntityA#4]
Fetching entity: [io.github.zforgo.stackoverflow.quarkus.model.EntityA#4]
select entitya0_.id as id1_0_0_ from EntityA entitya0_ where entitya0_.id=?
```

**Solution #3 use separated services and different transactions**

Although I prefer this one it needs the most efforts. The original code doesn't fit for SOLID principles at all. The idea is

1. create an other bean which has a new transaction boundary using `@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)` annotation
2. Move event handler into a separated event listener class becase since JPA 2.2 eventlistener supports CDI injection
3. In the listener class inject that service bean and call the desired method.

But due to this [open bug](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6948) I couldn't check it.